# What happens after a thread's run() has returned?

Tags: java, multithreading

Currently I'm learning threads in java. I'm wondering what happens when a thread's run() has returned(which means the thread is dead)? For example:

```
public class ThreadA extends Thread {
    private Thread threadB = new ThreadB();
    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        threadB.start();  //It will take a while to finishes
    }
}

...
ThreadA threadA = new ThreadA();
threadA.start()
```

What will happen to threadA and threadB? Would they be garbage collected? If so, how and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start new thread in A, it will live until stopped. Then it will be garbage collected. When you start it, it became referenced by JVM thread manager, and so, will be fully completed  before GC.

At oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) you may se an example:

```
The following code would then create a thread and start it running:
  PrimeRun p = new PrimeRun(143);
  new Thread(p).start();
```

As you see, you need no keep reference to running thread.

Also you can test such kind of issues using `finalize()` method. It will be called, when it's object is collected.